# Issues converting stdClass to array

Tags: php, mysql, database, pdo

I have converted one of my websites to use PDO database queries. All the queries are working perfectly except one and I have spent all day trying to solve this problem and nothing is working for me so as a last resort I am asking for some advice here.

This is the function I am having the problem with

```
    public function getTransactions($iProfileId)
    {

        $rStmt = Db::getInstance()->prepare('SELECT * FROM' . Db::prefix(DbTableName::GIFT_TX) .
                                            'WHERE profileId = :profileId ' .
                                            'ORDER BY createDate ASC, txId ASC');
        
        $rStmt->bindValue(':profileId', $iProfileId, \PDO::PARAM_INT);

        $rStmt->execute();
        $this->getTxs = $rStmt->fetch(\PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
        Db::free($rStmt);
        
                    
        return $this->getTxs;
    }
```

It returns a single row even though there are many others and as an object

```
object(stdClass)#47 (8) { ["txId"]=> string(1) "8" ["profileId"]=> string(3) "861" ["type"]=> string(6) "credit" ["credits"]=> string(2) "25" ["createDate"]=> string(19) "2020-06-26 10:48:55" ["isDelete"]=> string(1) "0" ["price"]=> string(4) "0.05" ["merchant"]=> string(6) "PayPal" }
```

I need this to be returned as an array and to get all the rows with profileId = :profileId

I have tried everything I can find online and have had no success at all.

Comment: You only call `fetch()` once and you call it with `\PDO::FETCH_OBJ`, so you will end up with 1 row as an object!

Comment: PHP docs say... PDO::FETCH_OBJ (integer)
Specifies that the fetch method shall return each row as an object with property names that correspond to the column names returned in the result set.

Comment: I have over 200 functions and this is the only one I have an issue with.

Comment: On the [manual page of `fetch()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetch.php) *PDO::FETCH_OBJ: returns an anonymous object with property names that correspond to the column names returned in your result set*

Comment: Try `fetchAll()` with `\PDO::FETCH_ASSOC`.

Comment: You sir are a god! I was missing the All... Tried FETCH_ASSOC first but not with all... Thank you.

Comment: @NigelRem Please add this as the answer.

Comment: There is already one for this, so mark that as accepted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code

```
$this->getTxs = $rStmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

If in doubt, check out the URL below:

```
https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetchall.php
```